# c# XML file writer

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file with the below formatting:
I'm trying to create the exact same file, but with different content.
I tried several options but I simply can't write before the XML header to keep the formatting of the file.

Can anyone help?

```
<MemoQResource ResourceType="NonTrans" Version="1.0">
 <Resource>
  <Guid>8380bf45-86cc-4c18-8ce3-11d69746d630</Guid>
  <FileName>do.txt</FileName>
  <Name>do</Name>
  <Description />
 </Resource>
</MemoQResource>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <nonTrans version="1.0">
 <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
 <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
 <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
 <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
</nonTrans>
```

This is the latest, not working code:

```
private bool ConvertFile(string infile, string outfile)
{
    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();


    XmlTextWriter writer0 = new XmlTextWriter(outfile, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer0.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer0.WriteStartElement("MemoQResource");
    writer0.WriteAttributeString("ResourceType", "NonTrans");
    writer0.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0");
    writer0.WriteStartElement("Resource");
    writer0.WriteElementString("Guid", Convert.ToString(g));
    writer0.WriteElementString("FileName", filename);
    writer0.WriteElementString("Name", name);
    writer0.WriteElementString("Description", description);
    writer0.WriteEndElement();
    writer0.WriteEndElement();

    writer0.Close();

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";

    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outfile, settings);
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("nonTrans");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0");

    string[] words = txtBox_source.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("nonTransRule", word);
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.Close();


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post some of the code you are currently trying to write the XML with?

Comment: The xml declaration half way down makes that XML invalid anyway.

Comment: Based on your sample it is not XML but rather couple text files that happen to have XML in them merged together... Searching for something like "how to append text to stream in C#" will give you answer. In mean time please review and [edit] your question and either keep XML part or merge text part as main question and adjust tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just sample bits of code to get you started on appending together the two chunks of XML documents - it should be refined/adjusted as necessary.

It shows one way using a `MemoryStream` to combine the 2 XML fragments in memory then writing that out to a file in one go.

It shows another one way just writing to a single file, then reopening it and appending the second chunk onto the end.

There are no doubt other permutations you could use depending on your uses cases e.g. created 2 temporary files, then reading them back, and writing to a 3rd file.

Only use the `MemoryStream` one if you want to avoid partially correct/temp files on disk, and have small XML documents.

### 1st Example - use a single MemoryStream, then just writes both parts to the stream

```
private bool ConvertFile(string infile, string outfile)
{
    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(infile);
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(infile);
    string description = "";
    string nontransrule = "123456\r\n123456\r\n123456\r\n123456";

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlTextWriter writer0 = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer0.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer0.WriteStartElement("MemoQResource");
        writer0.WriteAttributeString("ResourceType", "NonTrans");
        writer0.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0");
        writer0.WriteStartElement("Resource");
        writer0.WriteElementString("Guid", Convert.ToString(g));
        writer0.WriteElementString("FileName", filename);
        writer0.WriteElementString("Name", name);
        writer0.WriteElementString("Description", description);
        writer0.WriteEndElement();
        writer0.WriteEndElement();

        writer0.Flush();

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "\t";

        using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            sr.WriteLine();

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sr, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("nonTrans");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0");

            string[] words = nontransrule.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString("nonTransRule", word);
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.Flush();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outfile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ms.WriteTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConvertFile("dot.txt", "S:\\test.xml");
}
```

### 2nd Example - gets the XmlTextWriter to write the first part, then file opened in append mode to do second chunk

A way that does it just by writing to the same file and appending:

```
private bool ConvertFile(string infile, string outfile)
{
    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(infile);
    string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(infile);
    string description = "";
    string nontransrule = "123456\r\n123456\r\n123456\r\n123456";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outfile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlTextWriter writer0 = new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer0.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer0.WriteStartElement("MemoQResource");
        writer0.WriteAttributeString("ResourceType", "NonTrans");
        writer0.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0");
        writer0.WriteStartElement("Resource");
        writer0.WriteElementString("Guid", Convert.ToString(g));
        writer0.WriteElementString("FileName", filename);
        writer0.WriteElementString("Name", name);
        writer0.WriteElementString("Description", description);
        writer0.WriteEndElement();
        writer0.WriteEndElement();

        writer0.Flush();
    }

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.IndentChars = "\t";

    using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(outfile, true, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        sr.WriteLine();

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sr, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("nonTrans");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", "1.0");

            string[] words = nontransrule.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString("nonTransRule", word);
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.Flush();
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example output:

```
<MemoQResource ResourceType="NonTrans" Version="1.0">
  <Resource>
    <Guid>0c5beea5-f892-47f0-9898-247d5ded3d1a</Guid>
    <FileName>dot.txt</FileName>
    <Name>dot</Name>
    <Description />
  </Resource>
</MemoQResource>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nonTrans Version="1.0">
    <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
    <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
    <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
    <nonTransRule>123456</nonTransRule>
</nonTrans>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid XML - an [XMLWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) won't produce it.  The XML declaration needs to [go first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a file.

> The XML declaration typically appears as the first line in an XML document. The XML declaration is not required, however, if used it must be the first line in the document and no other content or white space can precede it.

If you really need to produce this, create two XML writers, one for the top document without a declaration, and one for the bottom document with a 1.0 declaration.  Then, merge the two files together using your file concatenation method of choice.  Something like (untested), `File.AppendAllText("file1.xml", File.ReadAllText("file2.xml"));`

[ReadAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.
This is a resource file.
The 1st part contains the info which required to import into a tool. The 2nd part is the container which holds the data. I tried to create the file with two XML writer but I don't know how to merge them.

Comment: One approach added

Comment: The standard xml methods are going to fail when trying to generate your invalid xml.  If you need the format posted I recommend using a StreamWriter which will not check the validity of the contents.  You can first write the resource data, use XmlWriter xWriter) = XmlWriter.Create(StreamWriter writer) to add the xml to end of the resourse file.